# Java Rest Call- multiple call in single session

Tags: java, rest

I have to make a call to third party website. but they requires login password.

I had one resturl to login to that system and another one to fetch details but how to do both the calls in single session I have no idea.

Here is my code to make a rest request

```
private static void restGetResponse(final String url, final Map<String, String> requestParams,
            final boolean isWriteToString, final StringWriter stringWriter, final OutputStream outputStream)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(getURLWithParams(url, requestParams));
        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = getHTTPResponse(httpGet);
        writeHTTPResponse(entity, isWriteToString, stringWriter, outputStream);
    }

    private static HttpEntity getHTTPResponse(final HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest) throws ClientProtocolException,
            IOException {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        addProxy(client);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpUriRequest);
        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        return entity;
    }

    private static void writeHTTPResponse(final HttpEntity entity, final boolean isWriteToString,
            final StringWriter stringWriter, final OutputStream outputStream) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need to bother about connection release
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                if (isWriteToString) {
                    IOUtil.writeToWriter(inputStream, stringWriter);
                } else {
                    IOUtil.writeToOutputStream(inputStream, outputStream);
                }
            } finally {
                IOUtil.close(inputStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me to make sesseion or share cookies accross multiple rest calls.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest using a http client library. I'm using the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x). It commes with a full [tutorial about cookie handling](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html). Must questions about the client are likely already anasered here, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-httpclient